# What are the values used for candlesticks

Tags: trading, charts

This sounds like an easy question but I googled for hours and could not find any info on this.

What is the value used for the open of a candlestick ? Was that value a market sell or a market buy ?
Vice versa what value is used for the close ? Is it the last market sell or market buy ?

I have a data set with market orders and I am trying to create candlesticks out of that data.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. It’s the first (open) or last (close) price traded, which can be buy or sell.